# Selecting variables as individual rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to select different variables into a temporary table as individual rows, but I'm being advised that 'there are fewer columns in the insert statement than values specified...' How would I insert these as individual rows?

```
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors)
VALUES( (@Error1),
        (@Error2),
        (@Error3),
        (@Error4),
        (@Error5),
        (@Error6),
        (@Error7)
      )
```

Comment: You have an extra pair of parenthesis around your variables. Remove the leading `(` and trailing `)`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99436b8b82dfdff8c56432e18422b288) (Voted to close as typographical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first parenthesis considered as first column, you need to separate them

```
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors)
SELECT t.Errors
FROM (VALUES (@Error1), (@Error2), (@Error3), (@Error4), (@Error5), (@Error6), (@Error7)
     ) t(Errors);
```

You can also leave it :

```
VALUES  (@Error1),
        (@Error2),
        (@Error3),
        (@Error4),
        (@Error5),
        (@Error6),
        (@Error7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of Values and columns defined in the insert statement should be the same. 
One of the workarounds you can try is to insert seperate statements like below:

```
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error1);
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error2);
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error3);
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error4);
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error5);
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error6);
INSERT INTO ##TestTable (Errors) VALUES (@Error7);
```